# Write a QList of QPair to a QSettings object

Tags: c++, qt, qlist, qsettings

I want to persistently store a list of integer pairs, using Qt Framework.

I thought of using `QList< QPair < int,int>>` as a type for the list, and to store them in an `.ini` file using `QSettings`.

Unfortunately, the function `QSettings::setValue` raises an error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘QSettings::setValue(const char [19], FavoriteList&)’
note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from QList< QPair< int, int> > to ‘const QVariant&’
```

It seems that it cannot cast that type to a `QVariant`. I tried declaring it with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`, but it didn't work, it raises the same error.

Example of code that fails:

```cpp
QList<QPair<int,int>> list;

if(!settings.contains("Radio/Favorites/FM"))
{
    settings.setValue("Radio/Favorites/FM", list);
}
```

How can I write that type to a `QSettings` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply don't have any compatible implicit conversion. The compiler doesn't know how to turn your list to a variant.

In fact, `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` shoudln't be necessary at all, at least for me the following code compiles with no errors:

```
  QSettings s;
  QList< QPair < int,int>> l;
  s.setValue("key", QVariant::fromValue(l));
```

EDIT: while it doesn't get compile errors, it will still get a runtime error because it doens't know how to serialize and deserialize a list of int pairs. So you will have to tell it how:

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const QList<QPair<int,int>> &l) {
  int s = l.size();
  out << s;
  if (s) for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i) out << l[i].first << l[i].second;
  return out;
}
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, QList<QPair<int,int>> &l) {
  if (!l.empty()) l.clear();
  int s;
  in >> s;
  if (s) {
    l.reserve(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
      int f, sec;
      in >> f >> sec;
      l.append(QPair<int, int>(f, sec));
    }
  }
  return in;
}
```

And also register stream operators for the type in the meta system:

```
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QList<QPair<int,int>>>("whatever");
```

Aaand.. it works!

```
  QSettings s;
  QList<QPair<int,int>> l;
  l.append(QPair<int, int>(555, 556));
  s.setValue("key", QVariant::fromValue(l));
  QList<QPair<int,int>> l1 = s.value("key").value<QList<QPair<int,int>>>();
  qDebug() << l1.at(0).first << l1.at(0).second; // 555 556
```

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html

The only type of QList you can store in a QVariant is `QList<QVariant>`, i.e. a variant can be a list of variants.

So you will need to replace your `QList<QPair<int, int>>` with `QList<QVariant>`, and as the variants in that list, you can store `qulonglong` which is a 64-bit integer, into which you can pack your two 32-bit integers, or figure out some other scheme (including having a list of lists, where each sublist has length 2 and is stored as a QVariant).

As an alternative, use `QList<QJsonDocument>`, and simply store all your settings as JSON.

Comment: Not quite true although a tad easier than doing it the "canonical" way which is quite verbose.